# A way to scroll up/down/left/right a static webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

Remember pac-man where you go off the side of the screen and appear on the opposite side? This represents a spherical map represented in 2D.
I'm trying to get the same behavior for a "flat" webpage, so when the user scrolls down, the entire webpage, text, images, etc, moves with the scroll. When it reaches the bottom of the webpage, the "top" of the webpage comes in to view from the bottom, like pac-man.

The same would happen side-to-side or left-to-right, except instead of using the mouse wheel, they would hold down the middle mouse button and move the mouse left and right to pan side-to-side.

How to get the hotkeys to work doesn't concern me, I'm just looking for the "spherical panning" behavior, based on user control of the mouse or keyboard, not a predefined animation or movie.

Comment: to project a spherical image onto a two dimensional plane is a pretty big question in and of itself. Are you just looking for how to navigate around an already mapped two dimensional map?

Comment: I'm just asking how to horizontally and vertically scroll a web page. This would let you scroll horizontally to the right forever, but the same content would be moving across the screen, not new content. That's why it's different from an infinite scroll. It's more like a "panning".

The reason I said spherical is because that's what the pac-man landscape is, even though you might play it on a 2D screen, since you go off the screen and come back on the opposing side, this represents walking on the equator of a sphere for example.